# Terminal Services 2003 Require accounts logging in to have a password

Tags: remote, service, terminal, desktop

I am required to look after a Terminal Services 2003 machine.  Occasionally company staff will create a new Active Directory user with no password and grant that user permission to login to the Terminal Services machine.  This machine is exposed to the internet on port 3389.

How can I tell Terminal Services to reject login if the user account's password is blank?

Comment: This is a people/process problem. Fix that.

Comment: I am following that path, and have explained to the staff the issues with what they're doing.  However, if I can prevent login with an empty password it solves my problem once and for all.

Comment: Adding a comment to this since I just saw it in my history.   We removed the server from the internet so it was no longer exposed at all.  Also enforced a password policy.  The machine is long since retired.  Looking back I cannot believe 3389 was ever on the open internet.  It was a different time!